# How to use Shiny.setInputValue() with the shinyjs package?

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

With a Javascript snippet in Chrome devtools, I can use `Shiny.setInputValue('input',0)` while my Shiny app is running to reset the value of an actionButton. It works well and I only need that one line.

However, I would like to use it inside my app with *shinyjs*.
Here is what I have in my .js script (Note that yes, shinyjs is properly set up and I am using it for many other functions throughout my app).

```
shinyjs.zeroInput = function(inputID) {
  Shiny.setInputValue(inputID, 0);
};
```

I have button **A** which once clicked needs to reset button **B** to zero:

```
observeEvent(input$mybuttonA, {
   shinyjs::js$zeroInput("mybuttonB")
})
```

This does not work and the chrome Javascript console outputs this when button **A** is clicked:
[image: Javascript Console output]

Note that using `Shiny.setInputValue("mybuttonB",0)` in the Chrome Javascript console works like a charm. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.

All I needed to do was convert the javascript function argument into a string:

```
shinyjs.zeroInput = function(inputID) {
  Shiny.setInputValue(String(inputID), 0);
};
```